# Percent encoded reserved characters in a path / url?

Tags: http, url, encoding, character-encoding

Example path:

```
/foo/boom%2Fpew/bar/
```

Doing `urldecode` `%2F` returns `/`, which is the folder separator.

Clearly, doing this doesn't look like a good idea, but I am interested in what problems it could cause.

Also, do the same problems apply to other characters such as `#?+`? Is it fine to allow a `percent-encoded` version of them in path?

Answer (score 2):

The `/` character is reserved in certain contexts in URLs, and percent encoding may change its meaning. In this case, `/` is a separator between segments of the path part (not “folders”; it is entirely up to the server to map the segments to folder names or to something else or just treat the path part as indivisible), whereas `%2F` is not; it stands for `/` as part of a segment. What this actually causes depends on the server or other software that is interpreting the URL.

Reference: STD 66 aka. [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I was looking for something perhaps less objective. more like example cases of why "it's ok" / "it's not ok". I feel this question is interesting but maybe off topic. Feel free to edit and improve it! ty

Comment: SO is for questions that can be answered objectively on factual grounds, so if you want other types of answers, it is indeed off-topic, and you should ask elsewhere, and differently, and specify what kinds of answers you like.